# Azure SQL Database - How to Prioritise certain Users / Queries

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a database which has multiple users and processes running multiple types of queries. Some of these queries are critical, some of them are not. I want to avoid the possibility that a critical process isn't run if the database is busy handling another query or task, and so I'm trying to establish a way to either:

- Create some form of hierarchy or priority list for queries so that a critical process is always prioritised
- Restrict resource allowance based on user / group so that critical processes always have the lion's share of resources earmarked to it

Looking around I've found `SQL Server Resource Governor` which seems to do the second option, but this is only available for `SQL Server` and **not** `Azure SQL`. Is there an alternative or another way I can achieve this goal that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/resource-governance-in-azure-sql-database/), it says we have 3 ways to govern resources in Azure SQL Database. But SQL Server Resource Governor is no supported in Azure SQL. So we have only 2 ways left:

1. [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects#job-limits-and-notifications):

> Azure SQL Database also uses Windows Job Objects for process level resource governance

2. [Windows File Server Resource Manager (FSRM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/storage/fsrm/fsrm-overview):

> Windows File Server Resource Manager (FSRM) for storage quota management.